# R rlang: handle NULL arguments?

Tags: r, tidyverse, rlang

I want to use an optional argument that has default `NULL` value to a `dplyr` function (say `count()`). If I use the standard procedure with `!!enquo()`, I get the error message: **error: Column `NULL` is unknown**.

Interestingly, `rlang/tidyverse` allows for missing values, so one trick could be to convert to missing if NULL, but seems quite dirty (esp. if I want to use `facet_grid` after, that accepts NULL but not missing).

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE), 
             b = sample(LETTERS[3:4], 100, replace = TRUE), 
             value = rnorm(100,5,1))

f2 <- function(df, group_var1=a,  group_var2=NULL, group_var3) {
  res <- df %>%
    count({{group_var1}}, {{group_var2}}, {{group_var3}})

  print(res)
  ggplot(aes(x=a, y=n), data = res)+
    geom_col() +
    facet_grid(row= enquo(group_var2))
}

f2(df, group_var1 = a, group_var2=b)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   a     b         n
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 A     C        26
#> 2 A     D        29
#> 3 B     C        16
#> 4 B     D        29


f2(df, group_var1 = a)
#> Error: Column `NULL` is unknown
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: 1 . I ran your code in a new session of the r console with an empty .GlobalEnv. The last two rows throw the following error ```Error: object 'a' not found```. 2. When generating random numbers ```set.seed()```.

Comment: When I run the code, the last two rows throw the the Error the same as Matifou.

Comment: This must be a version issue, the `{{}}` was implemented in rlang version 0.4 I believe, do you have that version, and the latest version of dplyr/tidyverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `group_by` nor `count` will accept `NULL` values. So you have to first create a quosures object using `enquos` and subset the `NULL` values. Since `count` is just a wrapper for `tally` and `group_by`, we can just group and count by hand using the `group_by_at` scoped version of `group_by`.

```r
f2 <- function(df, group_var1=a,  group_var2=NULL, group_var3) {

grps <- enquos(a = group_var1, b = group_var2, c = group_var3, .ignore_empty = "all")

  # this removes the NULL values

  grps <- grps[map_lgl(grps, ~ !quo_is_null(.))]

  res <- df %>%
    group_by_at(grps) %>% 
    tally() %>% 
    ungroup()

  print(res) 
}
```

This does a fine job creating the `res` data frame:

```
> f2(df, group_var1 = a, group_var2=b)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  a     b         n
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 A     C        20
2 A     D        30
3 B     C        22
4 B     D        28
> f2(df, group_var1 = a)
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  a         n
  <chr> <int>
1 A        50
2 B        50
```

However, we encounter problems again when trying to create the plot. `enquo` creates a quoted object, so `NULL` becomes `"NULL"` (more accurately `NULL`), so ggplot does not know how to handle it. So I think a conditional statement is the way to go:

```
f2 <- function(df, group_var1=a,  group_var2=NULL, group_var3) {

  grps <- enquos(a = group_var1, b = group_var2, c = group_var3, .ignore_empty = "all")

  grps <- grps[map_lgl(grps, ~ !quo_is_null(.))]

  res <- df %>%
    group_by_at(grps) %>% 
    tally() %>% 
    ungroup()

  print(res)

  if (quo_is_null(enquo(group_var2))) {
    ggplot(aes(x=a, y=n), data = res)+
      geom_col()
  } else(
    ggplot(aes(x=a, y=n), data = res)+
      geom_col() +
      facet_grid(row= enquo(group_var2))
  )

}
```

## Update based on Matifo's comments:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
df <- tibble(a = sample(LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace = TRUE), 
             b = sample(LETTERS[3:4], 100, replace = TRUE), 
             value = rnorm(100,5,1))

f2 <- function(df, group_var1=a,  group_var2=NULL, group_var3) {

  grps <- enquos(a = group_var1, b = group_var2, c = group_var3, .ignore_empty = "all")
  grps <- grps[map_lgl(grps, ~ !quo_is_null(.))]

  res <- df %>%
    count(!!!grps) 

  print(res)

  ggplot(aes(x=a, y=n), data = res)+
    geom_col() +
    facet_grid(row= enquos(group_var2))
}

f2(df, group_var1 = a, group_var2=b)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   a     b         n
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>
#> 1 A     C        29
#> 2 A     D        33
#> 3 B     C        18
#> 4 B     D        20

f2(df, group_var1 = a)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   a         n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 A        62
#> 2 B        38
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I made a few changes, slightly more compact: using `count(!!!grps)`. And I realized one can simply use `facet_grid(row= enquos(group_var2))` which will work in each case!

Comment: Very nice, added to the answer for completeness's sake

Comment: great, I took the liberty to update further, the `facet_grid(row= enquos(group_var2))` is definitely the easiest!